# Finding every combination of elements that includes one value from each row in a 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm using larger arrays in my project, but to simplify, let's say we have this 3x3 array:

```
$a = Array( Array(1,2,3),
            Array(4,5,6),
            Array(7,8,9) );
```

I want to find every combination of sums that includes one value from each row, i.e., 1+4+7, 1+4+8, 1+4+9, 1+5+7, 1+5+8, 1+5+9, 1+6+7, 1+6+8, 1+6+9, 2+4+7, 2+4+8, 2+4+9, 2+5+7, ...

Hopefully the pattern is evident. I tried a nested loop first (columns, then rows), but that didn't provide all the combinations. After quite a bit of searching, I feel confident that the solution requires recursion, but every time I try to write a recursive function for this, I get confused.

While working code will be very much appreciated, what's perhaps more important to me is *understanding* the problem and the solution.

Comment: If you posted your non-working code perhaps someone could help you in understanding where the problems is.

Comment: I deleted it precisely because it doesn't work. Most of what I've done to understand this is scribbled on paper.

Comment: It is not easy to explain for beginners like us. But this problem is the exact match for finding the best path to reach top-left corner to bottom-right corner of the matrix. For the above scenario we should find the distance of every possible path to reach the destination. Let say a footballer at top-left corner and he need to reach out to goal post at Minimal distance for that you need to calculate all possible distance and get the minimum of it. Like that you should proceed.. Let me know if you need the solution. I'm really happy to help you. Thanks BTW.

Comment: one important factor for potential solution is to know if the array's rows are all equal in number of columns (e.g. square matrix) as in your example ?

Comment: @dev101: Good point. No. In my project, it's more like 8 rows and 50 columns at maximum. It varies, but the number of rows and columns are independent.

Comment: maybe this can help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/  It's for 1D array, but you might get better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @dev101: Good find! I'll spend some time looking at it and see how I might modify it to suit my problem.

Comment: Having the tree as a visual aid helps. I can walk through it and see what's happening at each node. Changing the approach to address a two-dimensional array with the constraints I have (one value from every row) is a challenge.

Comment: @svadhisthana said in a now-deleted, non-answer back in 2019: "After more searching, I found a solution here: https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/4688876

I tested it with my example data above, and it provided exactly the combinations I needed. Using array_map to find the sums as in Nick's answer works as expected.

To my surprise, it doesn't rely on recursion but rather three nested loops. Hopefully I can wrap my head around how it works."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an unknown number of rows and columns in the array, the best way to get the result you want is to use recursion (otherwise you will have to write an arbitrary number of nested loops). This function recurses over each row in the array and returns one of two results:

1. If we're at the last row in the array, return that row;
2. Otherwise, return the cross product (using two nested `foreach` loops) between the current row and the result from the balance of the array. We use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to both get the current row, and remove it from the array.

Here is the code:

```
function find_paths($array) {
    if (count($array) == 1) return $array[0];
    $output = array();
    foreach (array_shift($array) as $v1) {
        foreach (find_paths($array) as $v2) {
            $output[] = array_merge(array($v1), is_array($v2) ? $v2 : array($v2));
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Using your example data:

```
$a = Array( Array(1,2,3),
            Array(4,5,6),
            Array(7,8,9) );
$combinations = find_paths($a);
```

The function does this series of operations:

1. take the cross product of row 1 `(1, 2, 3)` with the output of the function for the balance of the array `((4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))`;
2. *First recursion*: take the cross product of row 2 `(4, 5, 6)` with the output of the function for the balance of the array `((7, 8, 9))`;
3. *Second recursion*: At this point we only have one row remaining in the array `(7, 8, 9)`, so we return it;
4. *First recursion*: Compute the cross product of `(4, 5, 6)` with `(7, 8, 9)` = `((4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9))` and return that;
5. Take the cross product of `(1, 2, 3)` with `((4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9))` and return that.

Giving an output of:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 7 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 8 )
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 9 )
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 7 )
    [4] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 )
    [5] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 9 )
    [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 )
    [7] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 [2] => 8 )
    [8] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 )
    [9] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 7 )
   [10] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 8 )
   [11] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 9 )
   [12] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 7 )
   [13] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 )
   [14] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 9 )
   [15] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 )
   [16] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 8 )
   [17] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 )
   [18] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 7 )
   [19] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 8 )
   [20] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 9 )
   [21] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 7 )
   [22] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 )
   [23] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 9 )
   [24] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 )
   [25] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 8 )
   [26] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 )
)
```

If you then want to get the sums, you can simply use an [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) on the array, calling [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to get the sum of each element:

```
$sums = array_map(function ($v) { return array_sum($v);}, $combinations);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 13
    [4] => 14
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 14
    [7] => 15
    [8] => 16
    [9] => 13
   [10] => 14
   [11] => 15
   [12] => 14
   [13] => 15
   [14] => 16
   [15] => 15
   [16] => 16
   [17] => 17
   [18] => 14
   [19] => 15
   [20] => 16
   [21] => 15
   [22] => 16
   [23] => 17
   [24] => 16
   [25] => 17
   [26] => 18 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7UvS6b)

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering with this for some time, I found another solution that's much faster and uses a lot less memory than either Nick's or my original answers. This becomes important when using larger and more numerous arrays. Instead of 3 by 3 (27 combinations), try 9 by 9 (134 million combinations), for example.

Nick still deserves the accepted answer for providing code that not only works as asked, but is well-explained. Also, this code borrows some of the logic from Nick's code.

The performance trick is that instead of finding all the combinations and then getting the sums, we only gets the sums. That way, we're not creating a potentially massive array of arrays, but just one potentially massive array.

Edit: Passing `$sums` by reference instead of using `array_merge` saves significantly more time and memory. Code updated.

```
function combo_sums($arrays, $sum = 0, &$sums = []) {
    $array = array_shift($arrays);
    if (count($arrays) > 0)
        foreach ($array as $value)
            combo_sums($arrays, $sum + $value, $sums);
    else
        foreach ($array as $value)
            $sums[] = $sum + $value; # These are the final sums.
    return $sums;
}
```

Comment: If you only want the sums this is definitely a more efficient way to do that.

Comment: @Nick: I needed to understand how to traverse the arrays correctly before I could get to the point where I could just deal with sums. Thinking recursively was a learning experience. Thanks again!